# System versioned table duplicate rows

Tags: mariadb, innodb

I have tables (MariaDB 10.5.19; InnoDB) that I update periodically with data from an API.
Since I enabled system_versioning however, I get a new row, even if all columns keep their same value. I want the system versioned data to only contain distinct historical data.

I'm currently using `INSERT INTO [...] ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` however `REPLACE INTO` and `UPDATE` also result in new history rows.

Answer (score 0):

I have since found a way to do, what I already knew was what had to be done (compare the value of every single new column with it's old value and olny insert/update if there is at least one difference), but in a way that is elegant enough for my ego:

```
INSERT INTO
    sv_test 
SELECT 
    3, 'c'
-- here be magic
EXCEPT SELECT * FROM sv_test
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    id = VALUES(id),
    Column1 = VALUES(Column1)
```

MariaDBs `except` statement does the comparing of the data for me.

(n.b. the not-so-pretty bit of listing all columns in the `update` part is already present and not part of my system_versioning problem)